# How shall I set up Google Voice to use the internal microphone of my laptop?

Tags: google-voice

I was wondering how to set up Google Voice to use the internal microphone of my laptop. I don't find such settings my Google Voice account.

In case it may be needed, my OS is Ubuntu 10.10 and laptop is Lenovo T400.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Voice doesn't ring your computer directly unless you have an active Gmail window at all times.

To enable call forwarding to Gmail, go to *Google Voice settings* → *Phones* and click **Add another phone**, then follow the directions.

To configure the internal microphone to work with Gmail, you first need to have the drivers properly setup and configured. Once the microphone is configured, go to *Settings* → *Chat* in Gmail (or [click this link](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#settings/chat)), then look at the **Voice and video chat** section and select the appropriate device in the **Microphone** drop-down. If there are no options to change, [install the video plugin](http://www.google.com/chat/video) and refresh the page.

Comment: Thanks! I found my problem hasn't actually been solved. I have chosen "Internal Audio Analog Stereo" in "Settings -> Voice and video chat -> Microphone:". But when I click "Verify your settings", it doesn't work. Neither can I speak to others using Google Talk. I wonder why?

Comment: @Tim: That's a question to be asked on SuperUser.